# Javascript rich text editor that allows locking regions

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor

I'm looking for a rich text editor that allows for locking regions so that they can't be edited by the user. These locked regions would contain markup, not just plain text. TinyMCE has a plugin to support this but it is quite buggy.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a PDF form instead?

Comment: The issue with a PDF form is that it will cause me to loose the rich edit features.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the RTE contain the content you don't want edited, why not just put multiple editors around only the areas you want users to edit?

The problem I see with doing it the other way is that you could have individual nodes within the editable text with `contenteditable` off, but those nodes could still be part of a larger edit (e.g., they could be deleted). To truly prevent them being edited you'd have to check the current selection whenever it changed and disable all user actions until the selection didn't include the locked content. Even if you did that, it would be tricky to make sure that a user didn't add content in a place they weren't supposed to (before the first node, say, assuming the first node was locked).